# Represent a list of addresses in google maps using jsp

Tags: google-maps, jsp

Good evening. I have a list of addresses coming from my database joining jsp. I would like some help on how to enter this data in google map and represent on the map each one.
Would you have an example?

My list has the following attributes:
Address, state, country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSTL. Suppose you have markers data from markersList.

```
request.setAttribute("markers", markersList);
```

Create javascript array and fill it with markers using foreach.

```
<script>
    var markers= [
          <c:forEach var="marker" items="${markers}">
                {"id": '<c:out value="${marker.id}" />',
                "latLng": [<c:out value="${marker.lat}" />, //double without apostrophe
                           <c:out value="${marker.lng}" />],
                "title": '<c:out value="${marker.title}" />',
                "icon":  '<c:out value="${marker.icon}" />',
                "content": '<c:out value="${marker.content}" />'},
          </c:forEach>   ];
</script>
```

You can use wherever you want. For example, If you want to add markers on the map then,

```
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].latLng[0],markers[i].latLng[1]);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: markers[i].title,
      icon:markers[i].icon
    });
}
```

There are two projects that I tried this way before.

[angular map js and jsp](https://github.com/gurkan0791/AngularGoogleMap)

[default map js and jsp](https://github.com/gurkan0791/EmlakUygulama)

I hope this can help you